# TamperMonkey namespacing will not scope to top level domain

Tags: javascript, youtube, tampermonkey

I would like to run this TamperMonkey script on all YouTube.com sites exclusively:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTubeFakeScriptName
// @version      0.3
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

// Insert any JavaScript here.
```

Here's the problem, it's not scoped to YouTube only.
I have tried many alternatives:

```
// @namespace    http://youtube.com
// @namespace    https://youtube.com
// @namespace    https://youtube.com/
// @namespace    https://youtube.com/*
// @namespace    youtube.com
// @namespace    *
// @namespace    */youtube.com/*
```

Similarly with @include, here is what it said on http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php
The pages on that a script should run. Multiple tag instances are allowed.
Please note that `@include` doesn't support the URL hash parameter. Please visit this forum thread for more information: click.
Code:

```
// @include http://tampermonkey.net/*
// @include http://*
// @include https://*
// @include *
```

Along with many other possibilities, but I cannot seem to make scope only apply to YouTube, I can either:

- apply all TamperMonkey code to all websites
- apply no TamperMonkey code to all websites
- Have TamperMonkey script appear when extension is pressed

  - And be Green
  - And be Red
- Have TamperMonkey script not appear when extension is pressed

This last option is even odder, using match has strange behavior; I cannot even get my script to even appear when clicking the extension button if I use either:

```
// @match        https://youtube.com/*
// @match        *
```

But the script does appear if I don't use @match at all or use:

```
// @match        */*
```

Additional: I can confirm that using the following produces no script in the extension upon clicking Tampermonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTubeRandomAppHere
// @match        https://youtube.com/*
// @version      0.3
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
```

The solution required a few steps which are added to the original post at the bottom, so that others may learn as well. Thank you for your help.

remove @namespace 
add both:

```
// @match       *://*.youtube.com/*
// @noframes
```

Comment: i don't think `namespace` does anything, it's more for meta than execution.

Comment: FYI I have been reading this and many SO posts for ideas: http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php

Comment: and this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

Comment: So far all matches save the one below make the script not even appear
// @match        */*
and it just matches all urls

Comment: you'll need to show us the whole userscript file so we can try it ourselves.

Comment: @dandavis I have removed all my code except the lines shown now, same issue as before.

Comment: IDE warnings are not authoritative...

Comment: in the `@match` you don't need to include both `http` and `https` because `*` will include both of them and nothing more. source: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

1. The best way to specify sites in Tampermonkey is with [the `@match` directive](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40match). (Or use `@include` for more options but less performance and "safety".)
2. YouTube almost always uses the `www.` subdomain, so directives like
   `// @match https://youtube.com/*`
   will almost never match.
3. Occasionally, `http://` still works.
4. From your description, you *probably* don't want the script to work on iframed or embedded content.

So you want directive(s) that match the following URL patterns and exclude everything else:

```
https://www.youtube.com/*
http://www.youtube.com/*
https://youtube.com/*
http://youtube.com/*
```

See [the *Match Patterns* documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).  The pattern that does all that is:

```
// @match  *://*.youtube.com/*
```

Putting it all together:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YouTubeRandomAppHere
// @match       *://*.youtube.com/*
// @version     0.3
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

alert ("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Thank you, your script does work, however it does not solve the issue of GM_addStyle.

Comment: What issue of GM_addStyle?.  Oh, I see you *changed the question* a few minutes ago!  This is *unacceptable* and not related to the question as originally posed.  Once the original question is resolved, open a new question for the *separate problem*.  (In this case `GM_addStyle("body { color: grey !important; }");` may suffice for the additional problem.

Comment: I change the title not the question

Comment: You changed both, just not at the exact same time.

Comment: Fair enough, it was not intentional. The solution required a few steps which are added to the original post at the bottom, so that others may learn as well. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
// @namespace    https://youtube.com
```

to

```
// @match        https://youtube.com/*
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but I have already attempted this myself.

Comment: Bummer, thought that was the problem

Comment: Thanks for the help either way.